# Where do i put the synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

Lets say i have a method who deals with a shared variable. Due to the complexity of the method a part of it needs to be encapsulated to another method.

So we have something like this:

```
private void methodA()
{
    //do something...
    //do something else...

    synchronized(shared_variable)
    {
        //do something...
        methodB(shared_variable);
        //.....
        //.....
    } 
}
```

now what i'd like to know is if i should synchronize the shared_variable in methodB or not. Actually i know that it is not necessary but this code somehow smells badly.

Any solution how to do things properly in such kind of situations?

P.S.

The reason i am asking is because later in the developement process methodB may be called outside of methodA. So if i do not put symchronization on shared_variable in methodB it wont be thread safe. But when i call methodB from methodA i have locked the shared_variable twice so it looks a litte strange to me.

Comment: Can you post your hypothetical code for methodB?

Comment: That entirely depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: Syncronization is at Object level not at method level.

Comment: Cant you synchronize the shared_variable inside methodB()? If thats bothering you. That way you wont have to deal with it inside the predefined method.

Comment: I believe that synchronization should be applied to the minimal possible scope, also considering a possibility of deadlocks if more than one lock needs to be obtained.

Answer (score -1):

By declaring `synchronized(shared_variable)`, you actually declare a monitor on `shared_variable`, that means that whenever a thread enters the synchronized block, it acquires a lock on the given object. Theoretically, no other thread will be able to achieve the monitor, until it is released by the initial thread, which happens when it completes the execution of the synchronized block (which includes the execution of `methodB`).

Comment: Despite the downvote, I still believe in the validity of my response. Can anybody argue? I'm open to good reasons.